# array.push replacing last value instead of adding to the array

Tags: arrays, struct

I am attempting to keep a log of when a user does certain things but when a new log event is reached the second log is overwritten instead of adding a new one to the array I am unsure as to why when push should not replace anything.

```
struct logger {
 bytes32[] who;
 uint64[]when;
}

mapping(address => logger) log;

function LogEvent( bytes32 _username, address _userAddress, uint64 _timestamp) public{
      log[_userAddress].who.push(_username);
      log[_userAddress].when.push(_timestamp);
}

function getlogs(address _userAddress) view public returns(bytes32[] memory, uint64[] memory){
    return(log[_userAddress].who, log[_userAddress].when);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Realized it was because I was using a call instead of a send, I am surprised to find calls making state changes though I thought that was outside of their capability